# Алгоритм вывода результатов поиска

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, ux

У пользователя имеется плейлист с некоторым количеством треков. Также имеется строка поиска: пользователь начинает вводить в неё название трека и появляется список результатов. **ВАЖНО:** перед выводом списка результатов из него удаляются те треки, которые уже есть в плейлисте.

Это порождает проблему в UX. Я приведу пример:

В плейлисте имеются следующие треки:

```
трек 1
трек 2
трек 3
трек 4
трек 5
трек 6
трек 7
трек 8
трек 9
трек 10
трек 11
трек 12
```

Пользователь хочет найти новые треки, чтобы добавить их в свой плейлист. Он набирает в поиске следующую строку: `трек` . Сервер получает строку, ищет подходящие записи *(подборка идёт в алфавитном порядке)* и возвращает следующий список результатов *(10 результатов)*:

```
трек 1
трек 11
трек 12
трек 13
трек 2
трек 3
трек 4
трек 5
трек 6
трек 7
```

Перед показом этого списка пользователю из него удаляются треки, которые уже есть в плейлисте. Итого, остаётся:

```
трек 13
```

Технически это удовлетворительно решение, которое в данный момент реализовано и работает. Но с точки зрения UX это выглядит крайне глупо, когда в списке результатов может быть слишком мало треков, а то и не быть совсем, хотя в базе данных этих треков предостаточно.

У меня есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы:

1. Отправлять на сервер не только строку с названием трека, но и список треков, которые уже есть в плейлисте. Вряд ли реализуемо, т.к. используется GET запрос, следовательно в тело запроса этот список не положишь, а в параметры класть список было бы ещё более сомнительно.
2. Выводить в том числе те результаты, которые уже есть в плейлисте, просто помечать их как "уже добавленные".
3. Не решать данную проблему, т.к. она, возможно, вероятна только в лабораторных условиях, а в реальности названия треков могут быть очень разнообразными и таких вот ситуаций не возникнет.

Так как вопрос могут удалить из-за того, что ответ на него "основан на мнении", я поясню конкретно, какой ответ я хотел бы получить. Мне нужно оптимальное решение *(либо алгоритм, либо UI/UX)*, которое будет корректным как с технической точки зрения, так и с точки зрения UX *(то есть список не должен быть пустым)* и будет решать мою проблему.

Comment: Не уверен насчет оптимальности, но можно к примеру получать запросом не 10 подходящих треков, а 10+[количество подходящих треков в уже добавленных аудио], где последнее получается предварительно первым запросом. После получения этих треков просто отсеиваются те, которые уже добавлены, и из оставшихся выбираются десять первых.

Comment: @EzikBro отличный вариант! А почему неоптимальный? Норм вполне. Ну да, с базы будет не 10 вариантов доставаться, а там 130 или 300, ну это не сильно неоптимально мне кажется. Надо подумать, может быть вполне подойдёт. Предварительный запрос только зачем? Можно прямо сразу в первом запросе указывать количество результатов, которое ожидается + 10.

Comment: Да, можно, но все-таки есть разница между обработкой 110 и 310 записей, а предварительный запрос, как мне кажется, будет побыстрее, чем обработка этих 200 лишних записей. В прочем, вашу структуру я не знаю, так что решайте сами, как вам будет удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

У вас вначале описан сценарий, когда пользователь уже добавил треки, то есть он уже чем-то пользовался и помнит, что у него есть треки в добавленных. В этом сценарии стандартное ожидание от контрола поиска примерно такое: "я хочу послушать трек 1, я помню, что он у меня есть, покажи его".

Далее вы пишите, что реализовали не совсем стандартное поведение поиска, а реализовали запрос типа: "я хочу поискать треки, которых у меня в добавленных еще нет". Чтобы такой запрос смотрелся органично, к нему надо пользователя подготовить: написать рядом с контролом поиска "Поиск по недобавленным трекам", например, а все добавленные хранить отдельно со своим поиском.

Или можно сделать что-то типа вашего варианта 2 :

> Выводить в том числе те результаты, которые уже есть в плейлисте,
> просто помечать их как "уже добавленные".`

То есть обработать привычный сценарий (поиск по тому, что есть) и предложить что-то еще дополнительно в результатах (поиск того, чего еще нет). При этом в результатах прописать, что вот результат поиска, а вот еще треки, которые можно добавить дополнительно по этому запросу.

```
Запрос пользователя: трек 1

Вывод результата запроса: трек 1 (уже добавлен)

еще треки
трек 11 (уже добавлен)
трек 12 (уже добавлен)
трек 13
```